# Загрузка изображений

Tags: jquery

Нужен совет: у меня есть страничка на асп.нэте, на которой есть галерея - карусель картинок, так вот, сейчас СНАЧАЛА грузятся картинки, а потом отображается все в виде карусели, надо чтобы загрузка картинок была невидимая для пользователя, т.е. отображалось, например, колесо загрузки, а потом уже готовая галерея. Как это сделать?)

Comment: а на какое событие у вас повешено вызов карусели на onload или document.ready, погоже js не сразу отрабатывает при загрузке дом. 

Comment: document

inphotofocus.com, тут можно посмотреть, грузится долго только первый раз, дальше кэшируется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
var pictures = new Array();
pic_num = 15;//количество картинок
pic_loaded = 0;//количество прогруженных картинок.
for(var i=0; i<pic_num; i++){
  pictures[i] = document.createElement('img');
  pictures[i].src = 'imagename'+i+'.jpg';
  pictures[i].onload = function(){ pic_loaded++; check_picloaded();}     
}
function check_picloaded(){
  if(pic_loaded==pic_num){
    //all pictures loaded. Можно открывать галерею и прятать колесо загрузки
    $('#loading_wheel').hide();
    $('#gallery_wrapper').show();
  }
}
```

Comment: т.е. #loading_wheel - это любой плагин-колесо?

Comment: Это некий объект(например, div) с картинкой крутящейся загрузки. 
Можно и плагин, но не вижу в этом смысла

Comment: а не легче закрыть карусель дивом с крутилкой-загрузкой и прятать его после инициализации карусели

Comment: возможно, но суть, вроде бы, это тоже что и было предложено....

Comment: а не легче закрыть карусель дивом// Не легче. Пока грузится колесо(между прочим, анимированный гиф) и див, пользователь успеет увидеть карусель. А это не соответствует условию.